# Multi-dimensional array - splice the full array based on indexOf value

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I currently have a multi-dimensional array, am am trying to splice a value with the index of it is a channel name which has just been removed, then removed that value where that value is.

But its not doing that, its always splicing the very last value, I have debugged to ensure the correct value is being passed that I want to remove but.....still to no avail, I don't have much experience with MD arrays but this is proving to be a pain thus far.

I have attempted to fiddle with the index but just always ends up the same or just the opposite result.

Here is the code as it stands right now for the splice function:

```
    function stasisEnd(event, channel) {
    console.log(util.format(
        'Channel %s just left our application', channel.name));
    console.log(channel.name);

    //This is where the channels are removed from the array once they leave or are kicked from the channel.
    var index = channelArr.indexOf(channel.name);
    channelArr.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(channelArr);
  }
```

This is what the array looks like with 3 arrays inside it:

```
[["1447667845.0","SIP/488-00000000"],["1447667858.4","SIP/477-00000002"],["1447667847.1","SIP/487-00000001"]]
```

And so far it always removes the last channel where I want to remove an array if it has the index off the channel.name value being removed so aka:

1. SIP/477-00000002 has been removed.
2. Remove the 2nd array based on that value.
3. Can continue to remove arrays based off the channel.name.

Hope you guys can shed a little light on this.

EDIT: I am aware this works on a single normal array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

channelArr.indexOf(channel.name); works only if "channelArr" contains one element that is EQUAL to channel.name, but "channelArr" do not contains "strings" but "arrays", thus it won't work. You have to cicle the entire array or use two simple arrays instead a MD one

Try something like this

```
var index = 0;
var foundIndex = false;
for( var i in channelArr ) {
  var channelArrElem = channelArr[ i ];
  if( channelArrElem[ 1 ] == channel.name ) {
    index = i;
    foundIndex = true;
  }
}
if( foundIndex ) {
  channelArr.splice(index, 1);
  console.log(channelArr);
  updateSip();
} else {
  // Something went very wrong and the channel wasn't there.
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense and works a treat, I was originally using two simple arrays..... but due to a bit of functionality I need to implement I have to use a MD array would be much more efficient and easier to manage I think. Cheers!